# Using State location as basis for user creation in beta app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I'm setting up the homepage of my Rails app to determine whether a new user becomes a beta tester or just signs up and is recorded in the database for when the app opens up more.

The goal is that a user would enter their information and after clicking "Sign Up", something like HTML5 geolocation would determine their location. Depending on the State they are in, they would either be able to enter the beta version of my app, create a profile, and get started; or they would sign up and be entered into the database for when the app opened up to more users.

I know there are plenty of ways to get the location, but is there a way to set it up so the State is the determining factor as to the whether the user gets created vs. stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
def USState < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns = :id, :name, :abbreviation, :available_for_beta, ...

  has_many :users

  def self.find_by_coordinates (latitude, longitude)
    # code here to determine what state coordinates belong to
  end

  ...
end

def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns = :id, :username, :password, :salt, etc.

  attr_accessor :latitude, :longitude

  belongs_to :state, :class_name => "USState"

  before_create :set_state

  def set_state
    self.state = USState.find_using_coordinates(self.latitude, self.longitude)
  end

  def can_participate_in_beta?
    self.state.available_for_beta
  end

  ...
end
```

Untested at the moment, but it seems like a good approach, especially if you plan to add more functionality dependent on individual states or provinces. This particular implementation for location (USState) could be further enhanced with inheritance, as well, with little effort.

**Edit**: Misread the question. Removed validation stuff and added before_create hooks.